# Clearing incoming agent contexts in node sdk is not working

Tags: dialogflow-es

- I have a dialogflow agent with a 'test_contexts' intent, with webhook enabled.
- When matching this intent,  I would like to control the incoming/outgoing contexts in the conversation, using fullfillments.
- I cannot remove a context from the incoming request from dialogflow.
- For example in the code below, if the incoming request contains context 'loggedin', it will not be removed.

**Fullfillments code**

```html
'use strict';

const { WebhookClient } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const { Card, Suggestion } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

exports.MyAgent = (request, response) => {

    // Create a webhookclient class
    const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

    // Create function to test context control
    const test_context = function(agent){

        // fails to remove incoming context, set previously in the conversation
        agent.clearContext('loggedin');

        // fails to remove/modify incoming context, set previously in the conversation
        agent.setContext({ name: 'loggedin', lifespan: 0 });

        // successfully removes contexts set at the current point in the conversation, however, fails to remove any incoming contexts (as the name suggests)
        agent.clearOutgoingContexts();

    }

    // Define which functions are called for which intents
    let intentMap = new Map();
    intentMap.set('test_contexts', test_context);

    agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
}
```

How can I remove a context incoming from Dialogflow?!

Comment: Can you give examples of which contexts aren't getting cleared out?

Comment: Sure. I've reworded this and provided a MWE above.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

agent.setContext({ name: 'loggedin', lifespan: -1 }); successfully removed the context.